# Count number of tabs per line of text file

Tags: c#, text-files, csv

I am trying to verify there is a correct amount of tabs in a large text file (8,000,000+ rows) before importing to SQL Server.

I think I need to do something like this:

```
int count = 0;
char tab = "\t";
foreach(char c in tab) 
{
    if(char.IsTab(c)) 
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

However, this is not correct.  I need to do this to verify that the file is in the proper format.

Comment: Is the file is a tsv ?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan it is a .tsv

Comment: Aha. You dont need a python code in that case. [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20544/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-tab-delimited-and-has-8-columns) are some great answers to check validity of a tsv. Very simple one liners. When you check if a tsv has the right number of columns, you automatically check the number of tabs.

Comment: You're validating that each row has the correct number of tabs?

Comment: @Shar1er80 precisely

Comment: @ShreyasChavan can I write awk scripts without Visual Editor though?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan If C# is being used, I think it's a safe assumption that this is on a Windows environment. Something from the UNIX StackExchange is nice, but probably not very helpful in this case.

Comment: Of the 8,000,000+ rows, do you just not import the rows that are "bad", or do all of the rows not get imported if you find a "bad" row?

Comment: It seems you should be specifying your input source as a string, then testing if each character of the string is a tab. It looks like this code is on the right track, just using the wrong variables.

Comment: @Kupiakos That is true

Comment: @Shar1er80 I need to grab the bad rows and fix them

Comment: If you have the option of programming in C, which would be very fast, it'd just be `FILE *f = fopen("file.tsv"); char c; int n=0; while (!feof(f)) if (fgetc(f) == '\t') ++n; printf("Number of tabs: %d", n); fclose(f);`

Comment: When you fix the row are you putting the row back into the file, so that your file will have all "valid" rows?  Then you import the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a large amount of data, you want to avoid loading the whole file into memory at once. Here is a solution that just loads one line of the file into memory at once and counts the tabs in that line. The results are saved to an `int[]` where each item in the array contains the count of tabs on the corresponding line.

```
int[] counts = File.ReadLines("myfile.txt")
    .Select(l => l.Count(c => c == '\t'));
```

**UPDATE**

If you simply want the total count of all tabs in the file, then you could do:

```
int sum = File.ReadLines("myfile.txt")
    .Select(l => l.Count(c => c == '\t'))
    .Sum();
```

Comment: How do I access the array  to sum all the elements? ...as I don't see an array declared anywhere

Comment: The counts variable is an array of ints. Number of tabs per line.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks. Im going to give it another go

Answer (score 3):

With `Linq` you can get your bad rows like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int expectedNumberOfTabs = 5;

        List<string> rows = new List<string>
        {
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5 \t col6",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5 \t col6",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5 \t col6 \t col7",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5 \t col6",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5",
            "col1 \t col2 \t col3 \t col4 \t col5 \t col6",
        };

        var badRows = rows.Where(row => row.Count(c => c == '\t') != expectedNumberOfTabs);
        foreach (var badRow in badRows)
        {
            // Fix the bad rows
            Console.WriteLine(badRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
col1      col2      col3      col4
col1      col2      col3      col4      col5      col6      col7
col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
```

Now I don't expect you to read all 8,000,000+ rows into memory at once.  I think you'd read them in one row at a time and deal with them one at a time, so the line from this snippet there you're really interested in is:

```
row.Count(c => c == '\t') != expectedNumberOfTabs
```

Which will identify a "bad" row for you to fix.

### Sample Approach

Because you're dealing with a massive amount of data you may want to try copying the lines from the file to a new file, fixing bad lines as you run across them.  Once you have your new "fixed" file, delete the original file, and then rename the "fixed" file back to your original file and import it into your database.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int expectedNumberOfTabs = 5;
        string originalFile = "MyFile.txt";
        string originalFileFixed = "MyFileFixed.txt";

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(originalFile))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(originalFileFixed))
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Count(c => c == '\t') != expectedNumberOfTabs)
            {
                // line = ...Fix the line
            }

            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }

        // Delete original file
        File.Delete(originalFile);
        // Rename the fixed file back to the original file
        File.Move(originalFileFixed, originalFile);

        // Import the file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
int count = 0;
string tab = "te\tst\t\t\t";

foreach(char c in tab.ToCharArray()) 
{
    if (c == '\t')      // there is no char.IsTab() method
    {
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Gives me this result:

> 4

Your original code was not working because you declared `tab` as a `char`, which can't be iterated. I changed it to a `string` and iterate the `string` as an array of `char`s.

This may not be the optimal way, but it is a working way based on your original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it before uploading, you could use a StreamReader so you don't load the entire file to a string. But I guess it could be slow. Maybe you could divide the file in equal chunks and have separate threads process it.

Here's a sequential solution:

```
            int count = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\file.txt"))
            {
                count += sr.ReadLine().Count(f => f == '\t');
            }
```